# How to override other hide button validations

Tags: android, validation, datetime, button

I am trying to hide a button using the View.GONE method. But since I have a lot of validations, I can't seem to hide the button in my latest validation. Is there a way to override all other hide button commands? There is nothing wrong with my logic. I tested them using Toasts. But the button simply doesn't hide. I tried making it not clickable. It doesn't work either. This is my code. I'm trying to hide the button if the date in my TextView is lesser than today.

```
SimpleDateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd-yyyy");
       try {
           today = dateFormat.parse(dateFormat.format(new Date()));
    } catch (ParseException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

       String chkdate = edate.getText().toString();
       SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("M-dd-yyyy");
       try {
        mydate = sdf.parse(chkdate);
    } catch (ParseException e1) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }

    try{
       result = mydate.compareTo(today);
       System.out.println("result "+result);
       }catch(NullPointerException e2) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e2.printStackTrace();
       }



       if(result < 0){
           don.setClickable(false);
           don.setVisibility(GONE);
           Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "button gone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
       }
       else if(result >= 0){
           don.setClickable(true);
           don.setVisibility(VISIBLE);
           Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                    "Button visible", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();
       }
```

Comment: You don't invoke `setVisibility` anywhere in this code. What exactly are you doing?

Comment: @Simas, as I explained in the question, since setVisibility wasn't working, I tried setClickable. Anyway the code for setVisibility has been added

Comment: Make sure it is View.GONE or LinearLayout.GONE

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess it's hard to explain like this. What I believe is that, you have to add the new validations where your other validations are. So that it doesn't conflict and it easier for you to debug

Answer (score 1):

you should use `don.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)`

```
....
if(result < 0){
       don.setClickable(false);
       don.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE)
       Toast toast= Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), 
                "button gone", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);  
                toast.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                toast.show();
   }
....
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you not need

```
 don.setVisibility(LinearLayout.GONE)
```

after
if(result < 0){

Comment: I have added it now. Please have a look